# I have a JQuery function that sets active based on hover, I want to automate this to avoid duplication of effort

Tags: jquery, html, css, automation

I have a fairly simple piece of JQuery that hides/unhides an element, based on which of the tabs are hovered over:

HTML:

```
    <div class="row col-sm-4">
      <ul class="text-center">
        <li><p class="chat-provider-tab tab">Chat Provider</p></li>
        <li><p class="operations-tab tab">Operations</p></li>
        <li><p class="proactive-chat-tab tab">Proactive Chat</p></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
    <div class="row col-sm-8">
      <p class="chat-provider helptip" style="display: none">Chat Provider</p>
      <p class="operations helptip" style="display: none">Operations</p>
      <p class="proactive-chat helptip" style="display: none">Proactive Chat</p>
    </div>
```

JQuery:

```
$(".chat-provider-tab").hover( function(){
    $(".chat-provider").toggleClass("activetab")
});

$(".operations-tab").hover( function(){
    $(".operations").toggleClass("activetab")
});

$(".proactive-chat-tab").hover( function(){
    $(".proactive-chat").toggleClass("activetab")
});
```

I'd like to automate this where possible, and have tried several methods, however haven't been able to replicate the success I'm having with the above method.

Thank you,
Suxors

Comment: What do you mean replicate it, this question is ambigious

Comment: What do you meant by automating it?

Comment: @AdamBuchananSmith & @JonH I'm no linguistics wizard, but by `automate`, I think they just mean take out the redundant efforts of having to write (or copy) the same listener over and over for each new `.tab` element. Not really automating, I know, but words are tricky. By `haven't been able to replicate the success`, I think they just mean they can't reproduce the same effect, in a simpler way that nullifies the need to write a new listener for each new `.tab`.

Comment: Yes, apologies guys. My goal was to simplify the code I was using, rather than creating a unique function for each list item, as it will grow in time quite considerably!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you keep the `.tab` elements in the same order as your `.helptip` elements, you could use something like this to remove some of the repetitiveness of your functions (so you won't have to write a hover function for each tab and helptip you add):

```
$('.tab').hover(function(){
    $($('.helptip')[$(this).parent().index()]).addClass('activetab');
}, function(){
    $($('.helptip')[$(this).parent().index()]).removeClass('activetab');
});
```

This defines one hover listener for all `.tab` elements, which will, on hover over, add the `activetab` class to the `.helptip` element whose index (within their parent) corresponds with the index of the `.tab` element's parent inside their parent (since your `.tab` elements themselves will always have an index of 0, I had to use their parents' index instead). On hover out it will remove that class from the corresponding `.helptip` element.

I also removed the inline style declarations, and used CSS to define `display:none;` for your `.helptip` elements, so that I didn't need to use `!important` in the CSS to change the display property (and since it's better to just use CSS to define the `.helptip` visibility instead of controlling each individually with JavaScript).

```
.helptip{
  display:none;
}
.activetab{
  display:block;
}
```

Here's a Fiddle for you to test with: https://jsfiddle.net/qsvnbz6t/

Comment: I'll give that a go and let you know, cheers Mark!

Comment: Works a charm, Thanks very much!